# Replace sub-string after and before of different sub-strings

Tags: java, json, string

Suppose I need to replace all values of "name" in the below Json object.

```
    String srt = "{\"name\":\"Jon\",\"calls\":[{\"name\":\"Jons\", \"number\":\"00000000\"}],\"missed\":{\"point\":{\"name\":\"Sara\"}}}";

str.replace("name", "Kiki");
```

Output:

```
{"Kiki":"Jon","calls":[{"Kiki":"Jons", "number":"00000000"}],"missed":{"point":{"Kiki":"Sara"}}}
```

This code output is not I needed

I have tried to do with matcher and ObjectMapper. Its not working.

After replacing name with "Kiki" the object should be

```
    {"name":"Kiki","calls":[{"name":"Kiki", "number":"00000000"}],"missed":{"point":{"name":"Kiki"}}}
```

Comment: What have you explored so far? Please show your work as well.

Comment: Updated with the implementation

Comment: Updated with the implementation

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following replacement with regex:

```
    str = str.replaceAll("name\":\\s*\"[^\"]+?([^\\/\"]+)", "name\":\"Kiki");
```

Or you can do a Json Parse on the string and use Json functions to remove / replace the 'name' attribute's value.

Solution with regex (full):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "{\"name\":\"Jon\",\"calls\":[{\"name\":\"Jons\", \"number\":\"00000000\"}],\"missed\":{\"point\":{\"name\":\"Sara\"}}}";
        System.out.println("Input: " + str);
        str = str.replaceAll("name\":\\s*\"[^\"]+?([^\\/\"]+)", "name\":\"Kiki");
        System.out.println("Output: " + str);
    }
```

output

```
Input: {"name":"Jon","calls":[{"name":"Jons", "number":"00000000"}],"missed":{"point":{"name":"Sara"}}}
Output: {"name":"Kiki","calls":[{"name":"Kiki", "number":"00000000"}],"missed":{"point":{"name":"Kiki"}}}
```

Comment: Someone found the answer not helpful. Probably he/she is not able to understand a regular expression or couldn't even try it. Updated answer with code + output.